# Differential equation system in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have to model a differential equation referenced to another one, i.e.

d(Pa-Pl)/dt=flow1
dPl/dt=Pl-theta

where flow1 is some function depending on Pa and theta is a constant.

The question is: How it is possible to model this equation systems in Anylogic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find this question a bit weird, but here it is:

[image: sd model]

where:

```
flow1=dPadt-dPidt
```

and

```
dPidt=Pi-theta
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, siempre me contestas vos, muchas gracias. Hay alguna forma de comunicarnos?

Comment: depende para que.. mucha gente me pide mi email pero luego se pasa pidiéndome que les haga sus modelos gratis... prefiero evitar eso :)

Comment: Hola Felipe, gracias por tu respuesta. No te preocupes por eso. Soy investigador de conicet y quiero abrir una linea de investigacion de simulacion en fisiologia utilizando dinamica de sistemas+sistemas multiagentes, utilizo anylogic para poder iteractuar con los medico y porque me parece una herramienta muy buena de modelado, asi que no te voy a pedir que me escribas ningun programa; pero sí me gustaría tenerte a mano por si tengo alguna duda de la  programacion.